# fast way to find the related nets from a file (python)

Tags: python, performance, optimization

try to find a fast way to find out the related nets of a net from a file.

```
R1 net net2 
R2 net net3
R3 net2 net4
R4 net3 net5
R5 net6 net7
...
```

if a net is connected to another net through R, then these nets are considered as connected.
In above example, net/net2/net3/net4/net5 are connected

i have a file containing over 1 million lines, i need to find out all the related nets of a net.
maybe 500 nets are related, and others are all redundant.

```py
def get_nets(net, file):
    related_nets = set([net.lower()])
    searched_nets = set()
    unsearched_nets = related_nets - searched_nets

    while len(unsearched_nets) > 0:
        snet = unsearched_nets.pop().lower()
        with open(file) as fi:
            for line in fi:
                if line[0].lower() == 'r':
                    rname, net1, net2 = line.split()
                    if net1.lower() == snet:
                        related_nets.update([net2.lower()])
                    elif net2.lower() == snet:
                        related_nets.update([net1.lower()])
            searched_nets.update([snet])
            unsearched_nets = related_nets - searched_nets
    return related_nets
```

the above code costs 2s for each snet searching, so if i get 500 related nets, then total time is around 1000s, is there any fast way to do this job?

Answer (score 0):

use networkx

```py
import networkx as nx

g=nx.Graph()
with open(file) as fi:
    for line in fi:
        if line[0].lower() == 'r':
            net1,net2 = line.split()[1:3]
            g.add_edge(net1.lower(),net2.lower())

    if net in g:
        related_nets = nx.descendants(g,net)
```